# Child processes generating same "random" numbers as parent process

Tags: python, numpy, random, multiprocessing

I'm having some problems with simulations using `concurrent.futures` and `np.random`.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
from time import sleep

def calc_g():
    sleep(1)
    u = np.random.uniform()
    print u

futures = {}
with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:

    for i in range(0,10):  
        job = executor.submit(calc_g)
        futures[job] = i

    for job in as_completed(futures):
        job.result()
```

My results in this simulations are:

```
python teste.py
0.590820857053
0.590820857053
0.590820857053
0.590820857053
0.890384312465
0.890384312465
0.890384312465
0.890384312465
0.391709923204
0.391709923204
```

If I remove the `sleep` function in the function `calc_g()`, results seem to be a little more random:

```
python teste.py
0.116725033305
0.919465043075
0.116725033305
0.116725033305
0.608303685887
0.59397039096
0.608862016487
0.800008484487
0.689917804793
0.116725033305
```

I think that it has to do with the generation of seeds that `numpy` uses. Python generates forks from the main program and the same seed is copied to child processes. As generation process of random numbers is deterministic after the generation of seeds, values from `np.random.uniform()` are the same.

Can someone explain this better, with examples?

How should I use `np.random` in parallel tasks to simulate randomness as coin tossing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For independent streams of PRNGs in multiprocessing, give each process its own [`RandomState`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html).  The simplest fix, change this line:

```
u = np.random.uniform()
```

To this:

```
u = np.random.RandomState().uniform()
```