# Why UUID4 duplicates when generated in multi processes?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, multiprocessing, uuid

Using macOS Mojave & Python 3.6.4 .

I tried to generate a huge number of uuid4s which I expect almost never to duplicate using multi processes and uuid4 in Python3. My code is below:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pandas as pd
from uuid import uuid4


for m in range(5):
    def insert_uuid(n):
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        df['uuid'] = [uuid4() for _ in range(1000000)]
        df.to_csv('uuid_{}.csv'.format(m), mode='a', index=False)
        print(m, n)
    p = Pool(4)
    p.map(insert_uuid, range(100))
```

I inserted these data (500M records) to RDB (BigQuery), and counted them. The query and its result is below:

```
with all_data as (
  select uuid from `test_dataset.uuid_0` union all
  select uuid from `test_dataset.uuid_1` union all
  select uuid from `test_dataset.uuid_2` union all
  select uuid from `test_dataset.uuid_3` union all
  select uuid from `test_dataset.uuid_4`
)
select count(1) as count, count(distinct(all_data.uuid)) as uniq, count(1) - count(distinct(all_data.uuid)) as diff from all_data
```

Result

```
|   count   |   uniq    |  diff |  
|-----------|-----------|-------|
| 500000000 | 499979736 | 20264 |
```

It is strange that as many as 0.0041% of the uuids duplicate. I know there is a very little chance that UUID4 duplicates.

Why is this happening ? I think this is related to genarating random numbers in the OS.

Comment: [Child processes generating same “random” numbers as parent process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49847794/674039)

Comment: Version 4 is supposed to be a random UUID. The collision rate is suspicious. You should consider filing a bug against Python3. It appears the existing machinery is not safe to use out of the box. That's an engineering failure (which precedes RTFM).

Comment: What is the value of the uuids' `is_safe` attribute?